# OData $expand does not include entities where expanded property is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an OData service build with WebAPI and EF 6. I use the fluent api to create my models. It works fine, but when I use `$expand` it omits entities where the expanded property is `null`.

This is a simplified example:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? AddressId { get set; } // Note that Address is optional
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street{ get; set; }
}


public class CustomersController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public virtual IQueryable<Customer> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Customer> q)
    {
        // I return IQueryable from DBSet here...
        return db.GetDbSet<Customer>();
    }
}
```

A `Customer` doesn't need to have an address. And If I query it like `/customers?$expand=Address` it will not include `Customers` where `Address == null`. It will only return the `Customer` entities where `Customer.Address` exists.

I guess it does an inner join, and therefore doesn't get the `Customer` entities that doesn't have an `Address`. **Is there any way to include customers where address is null as well?**

Current Output:

```
[
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Customer1',
        AddressId: 1,
        Address : 
        {
            Id: 1,
            Street: 'Some street'
        }
    }
]
```

Wanted output:

```
[
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Customer1',
        AddressId: 1,
        Address : 
        {
            Id: 1,
            Street: 'Some street'
        }
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Customer2',
        AddressId: null,
        Address : null
    }
]
```

The models above is an example. I actually got way bigger models, but I tried to keep the example as short as possible to provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427211/odata-expanding-null) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410257/odata-expand-does-not-return-entity-when-null) question, but I'm not getting any error. I just don't get the entities at all.

Comment: what is your `EF query` ?

Comment: I just return my `DbSet` as a queryable, so I don't do a query at all. I added the code to the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that the wanted output is the normal behavior for an OData service when using `$expand`. The error was caused by my mappings.

For some reason I had a bit of old code that made the `Address` required, even though the foreign key itself was nullable.

```
public class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        // Other code...

        // This is wrong!
        this.HasReguired(c => c.Address).WithMany(a => a.Customers);


        // This is right!
        this.HasOptional(c => c.Address).WithMany(a => a.Customers); 
    }
}
```

And because of the mapping, EF translated the SQL into an `INNER JOIN` instead of an `OUTER JOIN`.